# matrix, sub matrix with greatest sum

Tags: c#

The task: 
1. Make a matrix n by m and fill it with data from console.
2. Find the 3*3 sub matrix with the greatest sum.

```
{
    static int[,] ArrayReadConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter n:");
        int n;
        n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter m:");
        int m;
        m = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] data = new int[n, m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a new value");
                int number;
                number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                data[i, j] = number;        
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    static void SumOfPlatform(int[,] data)
    {
        int sum =0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int maxSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0) - 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1) - 2; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                    {
                        sum =+ data[i + k, j + l];
                    }
                }
                if (maxSum < sum)
                {
                    maxSum = sum;
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                }
                sum =0;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}\nPosition: {1} {2}",maxSum,x,y );
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int[,] data = ArrayReadConsole();
        SumOfPlatform(data);
    }
}
```

}
I wrote that code but something went wrong... It doesn't find position or sum of the matrix I enter. I know that 4x for loop is a bad idea just I didn't want to make another method just for that. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: `sum =+ data[i + k, j + l];` Is that supposed to be `+=`?

Comment: Is something unclear? Please help a newbie :).

Comment: I assume that by "sum" you mean adding all the elements of a given 3x3 matrix together. `+=` is an operator that adds the right side expression to the left side value, whereas `=+` is just an `=` with a redundant positive operator. In essence, you are reassigning `sum` to be equal to the cell instead of adding the value of the cell to `sum`.

Comment: Interesting, yes I used += first time but I had an error message so I 'fixed it' to =+. Ok I changed it back. Sum is correct now but x,y still won't work..

Comment: As far as a "better solution", this way gets the job done in a generally straightforward way, so any improvements would be either to aid in readability, enforce a particular programming philosophy, and/or would be opinion-based.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?

Comment: It always returns 0 0, while for example at that matrix
'0 0 0 0,
0 1 0 0,
0 0 0 0,
0 0 0 0,'
it should return 1 1 (left top element of the submatrix). How can I format text here?

Comment: That 1 would be in the second row, second column, which would put it in all 3x3 submatrices. As such, the sum of every submatrix would be `1`, and as the code is written, it only updates if `maxSum < sum`. After the submatrix at (0,0), every other matrix sum would be equal, not greater, so it will never update. Try putting the 1 in the lower left corner: 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 1

Comment: Silly me. The code is what I wanted to implement just my test was wrong (and that =+ += mistake).. I thought something bigger went wrong, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code for SumOfPlatform is working with only change from =+ to +=

```
static void SumOfPlatform(int[,] data)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int maxSum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0) - 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1) - 2; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                        {
                            sum += data[i + k, j + l]; //only Change
                        }
                    }
                    if (maxSum < sum)
                    {
                        maxSum = sum;
                        x = i;
                        y = j;
                    }
                    sum = 0;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}\nPosition: {1} {2}", maxSum, x, y);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //  int[,] data = ArrayReadConsole();

            int[,] data = new int[,]
            {
                {1,4,6,7,3,5,7,4 },
                {1,4,5,3,3,5,4,4 },
                {1,1,6,2,1,5,7,4 },
                {1,3,6,3,3,5,2,4 },
                {1,4,6,2,3,5,3,4 },
                {1,4,2,2,3,5,3,4 },
                {1,4,3,3,3,5,2,4 },
                {1,4,4,3,3,5,2,4 }
            };

            SumOfPlatform(data);



        }
```

Comment: Although  Abion47's help came faster and was as helpful as yours, he wrote comments what I can't tide so I accept your answer.